REGEXMATCH nested inside SWITCH
I have a sheet where column "M" might contain the words "Desktops" or "Laptops". I expect them to be written exactly like that.
If this is the case I want to extract either of these words in the corresponding cell of column "N".
What I came up with is:
=SWITCH(M12,REGEXMATCH(M12,"Desktops"),"Desktops",REGEXMATCH(M12,"Laptops"),"Laptops","Whatever")

This is supposedly in compliance with the syntax of both REGEXMATCH and SWITCH.
Regrettably it doesn't work and always returns "Whatever".

REGEXMATCH doesn't extract, it returns a boolean value. If you want to extract use REGEXEXTRACT.
=IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(M12,"Desktops|Laptops"),"Whatever")


EDIT: Extract both
To extract both Desktops and Laptops, you can use:
=LET(z,SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(Desktops|Laptops)|.","$1 ")," "),IF(TRIM(z)="","Whatever",z))



What if I wanted to extract BOTH "Desktops" and "Laptops" in case they are present simultaneously ?
